# Error in MATLAB: first input subs must contain positive integer

Tags: matlab

Is there any operation in MATLAB that removes zeros from number

```
150.0000  150.0000    0.0000
  143.0000  148.0000    0.0000
  152.0000  152.0000    0.0000
  152.0000  144.0000    0.0000
  146.0000  150.0000    0.0000
  149.0000  145.0000    0.0000
  148.0000  152.0000    0.0000
  152.0000  157.0000    0.0000
  157.0000  164.0000    0.0000
  160.0000  155.0000    0.0000
  154.0000  154.0000    0.0000
```

The reason I ask is because I want to use them in function called `accumarray` and I keep getting the error

```
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.
```

Thanks

Update: Eventually I would like to use as follows

```
[X] = round(x)
[Y] = round(y)
data = [X,Y,Z];
plotdata = accumarray(data(:,1:2),data(:,3));
surface(plotdata)
colorbar
```

Comment: How are you using the code? can you post the code that gives that error

Comment: The three columns I have, I want to use them to have a heatmap plot....

Answer (score 1):

```
[X] = round(x-min(x))+1;
[Y] = round(y-min(y))+1;
data = [X,Y,Z];
plotdata = accumarray(data(:,1:2),data(:,3));
surface(unique(x),unique(y),plotdata)
colorbar
```

`min()` moves your array to the upper-left corner of your matrix, basically removing leading zero rows and columns. The `+1` ensures it does not end up at zero, which gives the error in `accumarray`.

Comment: But with such a manipulation, isnt the value of X and x very different?

Comment: Isnt there a way, to keep x and y double and not integer and still use surface?

Comment: Of course it is. Just shift them back after the `accumarray` for your plot. Or, you might have used the solution I already gave you in my previous answer using `unique` which you can shift back.

Comment: Since you used different variable names this is actually not necessary, just plot using `unique` for `x` and `y`.

Comment: the problem is when i use unique.. it drastically changes my original x and y values that i want to use for my plot

Comment: it does not. It merely extracts the unique values from your array, which is unsurprising give its name. All it does is extract all values that appear and list them in ascending order, which is what you want for your axes on your plot.